# Shortest Intel x86-64 opcode for rax=1?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization, code-size

What would be the shortest Intel x86-64 opcode for setting `rax` to 1?

I tried `xor rax,rax` and `inc al` (in NASM syntax); which gives the 5-byte opcode `48 31 c0` `fe c0`. Would it be possible to achieve the same result in 4 bytes?

You can modify or read any other registers, but cannot assume that a specific value would be on any one of them from previous instructions.

Comment: Generally not worth using 2 instructions when `mov eax, 1` is only 5 bytes.  (And yes, it clears the upper32, just like every other write to a 32bit reg.)  If you're going for size over speed, the `push imm8 / pop` answer has a lot of merit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is a byte immediate encoding for push and a one-byte pop for registers, this can be done in three bytes: `6a 01 58`, or `push $1 / pop %rax`.

Answer (score 2):

With any known pre-conditions, there are some tricks that are more efficient (in terms of speed) than the push imm8/pop rax 3-byte solution.

For speed `mov eax, 1` has many advantages, because it doesn't have any input dependencies and it's only one instruction.  Out-of-order execution can get started on it (and anything that depends on it) without waiting for other stuff.  (See [Agner Fog's guides](http://agner.org/optimize/) and the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

Obviously many of these take advantage of the fact that [writing a 32-bit register zeros the upper half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register), to avoid the unnecessary REX prefix of the OP's code.  (Also note that `xor rax,rax` is not [special-cased as a zeroing idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) on Silvermont.  It only recognizes xor-zeroing of 32-bit registers, like eax or r10d, not rax or r10.)

---

If you have a small known constant in any register to start with, you can use

```
lea   eax, [rcx+1]    ; 3 bytes: opcode + ModRM + disp8
```

disp8 can encode displacements from -128 to +127.

---

If you have an odd number in eax, `and eax, 1` is also 3 bytes.

---

In 32-bit code, `inc eax` only takes one byte, but those inc/dec opcodes were repurposed as REX prefixes for AMD64.  So `xor eax,eax` / `inc eax` is 4 bytes in x86-64 code, but only 3 in 32-bit code.  Still, if saving 1 byte over a `mov eax,1` is sufficient, and LEA or AND won't work, this is more efficient than push/pop.